# How to delay a class from executing?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

So I have this:

```
(function () {
   // work
}).defer(1000);
```

For my admittedly weak understanding of javascript this executes an anonymous class after a second of wait time.

So I wanted to change it to something like this:

```
var newClass = function() {
   // work
};
newClass().defer(1000);
```

But this doesn't give me the delay for some reason.  I feel like these two code samples are exactly the same, I am wrong in this assumption?

Edit:

I'm using this [defer](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/?class=Ext.Component) method, sorry I thought it was a javascript thing.

Comment: Javascript does not have a `defer()` method.

Comment: @SLaks I'm sorry I've updated my answer.

Comment: "Classes", i.e. constructor functions, are normal functions.

Comment: *" I feel like these two code samples are exactly the same, I am wrong in this assumption?"* Yes, in the first example you are not executing the function you defined. In the second case you are. What you want is `newClass.defer(1000)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't define a defer method, so here is one that works (almost) like you expect:

```
Function.prototype.defer=function(delay){ return setTimeout(this, delay || 100); };
var newClass = function() {
   alert ("working");
   // work
};
newClass.defer(1000);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what defer method I'm using.

Comment: ok, then stike my first line, the invocation syntax is the same. Just don't call the function before you defer() it.

Answer (score 3):

```
newClass().defer
```

This **calls** the function, then calls `defer()` on whatever the function returns.

Comment: Is there any way I can call a sleep/wait for a second in javascript?

Comment: @Grammin: [What do I do if I want a JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951021)

Comment: @Grammin: No; you need to use asynchrony.  (`setTimeout` or promises)